# InstallScript and registry

Tags: installation, installshield, installscript

I have two .reg files, the difference between them is only in `Key` which depends on the version of Windows.

My registry file for Windows x86:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\NGG]
@="URL:NGG Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\NGG\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\wpf.exe"
"Test"="ika"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\NGG\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\NGG\Shell\Open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\NGG\Shell\Open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\NGG\\start.exe\" \"%1\""
```

The difference in Windows x64:

```
@="\"C:\\Program Files(x86)\\NGG\\start.exe\" \"%1\""
```

How can I make an install script (InstallShield MSI) which checks the Windows version and then uses this current registry file.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using .reg files for this. Instead use InstallShield's and/or Windows Installer's support for variable values in the registry, and specify either `"[ProgramFilesFolder]NGG\start.exe" "%1"` in an MSI-based installation or `"<PROGRAMFILES>\NGG\start.exe" "%1"` in InstallScript based installation as the value in the Registry view.

(Or possibly go even more specific by using Verb support in an MSI-based project. Or reference something like `"[#start.exe]" "%1"` for your path, assuming you install that executable with a filekey of start.exe - see [Formatted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609.aspx) for details.)